# Laravel 5 Protecting Routes with Middleware

Tags: authentication, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel 5, I just want to know how can I protect specific routes?  I'm using the default Authenticate Middleware to protect my routes which is only accessible if you're logged in. So i have this.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate'], function()    /* Admin only Routes*/
{
     Route::get('/brk/datalist', 'BRKDailyMailsController@datalist');
});
```

How can I protect the /auth/register only? without affecting the others like login?

Outside my route group I have this by default.

```
Route::controllers([
'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

I only want logged in users to access default register page. My logged in users is all admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can set middleware for specific route like this:

```
Route::any('register', [
    'as' => 'register', 
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@anyRegister'
]);
```

This way only logged in users will be able to "use" the /register page.

It is named "register" too so you can use it in your templates, redirects etc. by name.

And if it "passes" the middleware (user is logged in) the anyRegister action from AuthController will be executed.

Feel free to modify this as you need, it's just an example of how can this be achieved.

Comment: Route::get('/auth/register', [
 'as' => 'register'
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@getRegister'
]); does't work for me

Comment: You missed a comma before middleware key. And make sure your url and controller/action names are correct. Also I believe you don't need the keading slash in your route

Comment: Doesn't work for me Sir. I can still access /auth/register even if there's no logged user.

Comment: oh, one more thing. you're posting the data, right? So Route::get will only match the GET method. You should either define a separate Route::post or use Route::any for request method independent route.  Also if 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate' middleware works for the group of routes you might wanna try setting the same for single route too

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::get('/brk/datalist', 'BRKDailyMailsController@datalist');
});
```

Or you can use construct on first line in every controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```